# Ember routes: different URLs for wizard steps

Tags: ember.js

Usecase: wizard with a number of steps. Initally implemented using `{{partial currentStepTemplate}}`.

I want to refactor this to have a separate controller for each step. Initially did a `{{render currentStepTemplate controller=currentStepController}}` but unlike `{{partial}}`, render is not bound to the `currentStepTemplate` and `currentStepController` properties and it uses them as raw strings.

I created a route `/walkthrough/:step`.

The problem is that there's no specific model to be loaded on the route, but I need to know which template to render using the `:step` parameter that's only accessible in the `model` hook.

It doesn't look like a good pattern to use the model just as a way of passing the `step` parameter further to `setupController` and `renderTemplate`, but not sure of how else I could achieve this.

```
App.WalkthroughRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  steps: ["", "intro", "name", "photo", "create_course"]

  model: (params) ->
    @set('stepName', params['step'])
    @set('stepTemplate', "walkthrough/teacher/_step_#{stepName}")

    # Optional controller: used only if exists
    if @container.lookup("controller:#{controllerName}")
      @set('stepController', controllerName)

    return @steps.indexOf(params['step'])

  renderTemplate: (controller, model) ->
    @render()
    @render @get('stepTemplate'),
      controller: @get('stepController')
      into: 'walkthrough'

  actions:
    nextStep: ->
      step = @modelFor('walkthrough')
      @transitionTo('walkthrough.teacher', @steps[step + 1])

    prevStep: ->
      step = @modelFor('walkthrough')
      @transitionTo('walkthrough.teacher', @steps[step - 1])
)
```

Any hints/ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're trying to recreate how the router already works.  I'd move each step to routes under a resource.  Then your url would look like this:

```
#/walkthrough/step1
#/walkthrough/step2
#/walkthrough/step3
#/walkthrough/step4
```

with a router like

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('walkthrough', function(){
    this.route('step1');
    this.route('step2');
    this.route('step3');
    this.route('step4');
  });
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/musugiru/1/edit